# Increase maximum number of controller parameters accepted?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 4, how do you increase maximum number of controller parameters accepted? I need six but it only appears to accept a maximum of 5.

Comment: There is no limit imposed by Laravel.

Comment: According to this post there is: http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=2112

Comment: I don't know for Laravel 3, but in Laravel 4 there is no limit. I just made a route with 7 parameters and I received all values. You can check the test route: http://pastebin.com/0Vugjck6

Comment: Yes, it's fine how you did it... but try Route::controller('test', 'TestController');  and then accessing test/one/two/three/four/five/six with public function testController($seg1,$seg2,$seg3,$seg4,$seg5, $seg6){ return $seg6;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works like a charm:

**route.php**

```php
Route::get('test/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}/{param4}/{param5}/{param6}/{param7}', 'TestController@index');
```

**TestController.php**

```php
class TestController extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $params = func_get_args();
        print_r($params);
    }
}
```